# Microsoft Small Basic Program

Tags: smallbasic

haiku generator. A program that pulls randomly from an array of one and two syllable and put them into a new haiku poem following the syllable from 5-7-5

Using Microsoft Small Basic.

Comment: I tried this ....Name[1]= "An old silent pond"
Name[2]= "A frog jumps into the pond"
Name[3]= "splash! Silence again"
Name[4]= "Autumn moonlight"
Name[5]= "Hunter Beauchamp"
Name[6]= "a worm digs silently"
Name[7]= "into the chestnut"
Name[8]= "Lightning flash"
Name[9]= "what I thought were faces"
Name[10]= "are plumes of pampas grass"

Comment: tot=10 
TextWindow.WriteLine("array:")
For a = 1 To 10 
i = Math.GetRandomNumber(tot)
TextWindow.WriteLine(a+": "+name[i])

If a < 10 then 
remainder = Math.Remainder(a, 2)
If (remainder =0) Then
  TextWindow.Write(Text.GetCharacter(10)+"array:"+Text.GetCharacter(10))
  EndIf 
EndIf

If tot > i Then 
  For b = i To tot-1
    name[b]=Name[b+1]
  EndFor   
EndIf 
  tot=tot-1
endfor

Comment: Could you please put it into code form?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn’t a website to have your homework completed for you.

Comment: Unforshuntly I don't know how to put it into code... soryy Matthew I'm new here.

Comment: Mr. Martin Bean I add my solution I just asked about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the solution, i i may, is to make a 3 dimension array.

```
array["syllables"][1][1] = "red"
array["syllables"][1][2] = "Cat"
array["syllables"][1][3] = "The"

array["syllables"][2][1] = "reading"
```

and keep going with as many words as you like. then create 3 while loops
the first, while the number of syllables in not greater than 5 keep adding words, using the 2nd array dimension as an adder.
 so get random number that is not greater than the number of syllables possible for the rule. Once you have a random word. add that syllable to a number holder and make the while loop number you are at < total syllables.

in the second not greater than 7
and 3rd not greater than 5.

Hope that helps.